# A natural coding scheme of ECA rules reveals some regularities but leaves questions open

Tags: elementary-number-theory, dynamical-systems, symmetry, cellular-automata

This is a question about a coding scheme of numbers that might yield insights in cellular automata and the rules that govern them.

**Background**

Since Wolfram the rules defining [elementary cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_cellular_automaton) are given as decimal numbers, e.g. $254$, $250$, $90$, and $30$ (in the order of appearance in [A New Kind of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_Kind_of_Science)). In G. Martinez' paper [A Note on Elementary Cellular Automata Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5577) we find the following lists of equivalent and of classified rules , uniform (class I), periodic (class II), chaotic (class III), complex (class IV).

[image] [image]

I am interested in (arithmetic) properties of rule numbers that allow to determine their complexity and equivalence classes. So I played around with coding schemes and arrangements of rule numbers that allow to see at least something.

**A natural coding scheme**

The specific coding scheme I came up with goes like this: Write rule number $r$ given as a binary sequence $\langle r\rangle = \langle r_7,r_6,r_5,r_4,r_3,r_2,r_1,r_0 \rangle$  as a pair of binary sequences $r^0$, $r^1$ of length $4$  by the following mapping:

$r^{0} = \langle r_0,r_1,r_4,r_5\rangle$

$r^{1} = \langle r_7,r_6,r_3,r_2\rangle$

Writing $r^0$ below $r^1$ reveals that the scheme is quite "natural": $r_1$ describes the behaviour of black cells, $r_0$ describes the behaviour of white cells, and the two sequences are inverse to each other.

[image]

**The normal coding scheme**

Compare this with the "normal" scheme which maps $r$ to $r^0 = \langle r\text{ mod }16\rangle$ and $r^1 = \langle \lfloor r / 16\rfloor \rangle$:

[image]

**Plotting rules**

Rule number $r$ is plotted at position $(r^0,r^1)$ in a $16\times 16$ grid. Coloring the numbers by their rule complexity class (see above) gives an erratic pattern for the "normal" scheme:

[image]
Yellow = class I, green = class II, red = class III, blue = class IV.

Accordingly, plotting equivalent rules gives erratic patterns for the normal scheme:

[image]

For the "natural" scheme, the class matrix is symmetric and shows some interesting regularities:

[image]

And so do the equivalence classes of rules, here for the strong class III rules:

[image]

The symmetries and equivalences can be easily understood. The rules obtained from a given rule by

- swapping and inverting $r^0$ and $r^1$, i.e. reflecting $(r^0,r^1)$ at the second diagonal
- swapping the entries $r^i_1$ and $r^i_2$ for $i = 0,1$

yield respecitively

- inverted patterns (when evolving the rules from inverted start conditions)
- reflected patterns (when evolving from the same start condition)

and thus equivalent rules. Examples of equivalence classes of size $1$ can be found among the weak class III rules:

[image]

My question is: **Can the proposed coding scheme be used to define transformations (beyond reflecting and inverting) and (invariance) properties that allow to derive the complexity class of a given rule? If not so: (How) can it be proved, that no coding scheme can do this job?**

Comment: Your description of your "natural coding scheme" seems slightly inconsistent with regard to bit order: the text says $r^0=\langle r_5,r_4,r_1,r_0\rangle$ and $r^1=\langle r_7,r_6,r_3,r_2\rangle$, while the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnPDA.png) below it shows $r^0=\langle r_0,r_1,r_4,r_5\rangle$ instead and your [class matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaLLI.png) looks to me like it was probably drawn using $r^0=\langle r_5,r_4,r_1,r_0\rangle$ and $r^1=\langle r_2,r_3,r_6,r_7\rangle$. (FWIW, I'd recommend making $r_0$ and $r_7$ the most significant bits of $r^0$ and $r^1$ respectively.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Thanks for the correction. I immediately corrected the bit order. The matrix should be rotated, I'll fix this tomorrow. Symmetry and regularities are not affected, at least.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I rotated the matrices as well. By the way: The order of bits is the same as used by Wolfram et al: the highest bits to the left.